# NullPointer on MenuItem when loading controller

Tags: nullpointerexception, javafx, menuitem

Ok, I'm having trouble making a Menu with Menu Items.

I was following this tutorial ( http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/ui_controls/menu_controls.htm ), but when I run it I get a nullpointer error. My code looks like this:

```
@Override
public void initialize(URL fxmlFileLocation, ResourceBundle resources) {

    ventas.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {

        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent t) {
            FXMLLoader ventasloader;
            ventasloader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("VentasGUI.fxml"));
            Stage ventasstage = new Stage();
            AnchorPane ventas = null;
            try {
                ventas = (AnchorPane) ventasloader.load();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(PuntoDeVentaController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
            Scene ventasscene = new Scene(ventas);
            ventasstage.setScene(ventasscene);
            ventasstage.setTitle("Venta");

            VentasGUIController controller = ventasloader.<VentasGUIController>getController();
            controller.setUser(userID);

            ventasstage.show();
        }
```

...but even when I leave just the skeleton code that NetBeans automatically adds:

```
@Override
public void initialize(URL fxmlFileLocation, ResourceBundle resources) {

    ventas.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {

        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent t) {
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");
        }
```

...rather than get the "Not supported yet" I get the nullpointerexception. I looked at the docs on http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/control/MenuItem.html but I don't see that my event handler is empty, and it seems to be exactly the same as in the tutorial.

Anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't told where the NPE occurs so I guess here:

```
ventas.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
```

Further I guess that `ventas` is a JavaFX control which you have defined in your `.fxml` file.

There are two things which have to be done that a connection between the `.fxml` file and the Java code works.

1. Annotate `ventas` with `@FXML` in your Java file
2. Define the `fx:id` of the `ventas` control in the SceneBuilder (set it to `ventas`)

Comment: AARRGGgghhhh!!! I was so fixated on the controller that I forgot to go back and associate the "ventas" fx:id in the fxml file with the actual MenuItem! THANK YOU!